# Coq: import information about instances

Tags: typeclass, implicit, coq

```
Section Definitions.

  Definition eq_dec X := forall x y : X, {x=y} + {x <> y}.
  Existing Class eq_dec.

  (* Any function that uses eq_dec. Doesn't matter -- ↓ ↓ ↓ *)
  Definition f {X: Type} {DecX: eq_dec X} (x y: X) := x = y.

End Definitions.

Section MySection.

  Context {T: Type}.
  Hypothesis TEqDec: eq_dec T.

  Inductive myType :=
  | C: T -> myType.

  Instance myTypeEqDec : eq_dec myType.
  Proof. ... Defined.

  (* Everything is ok *)
  Example example1: forall (t1 t2: myType), f t1 t2.
  Proof. ... Qed.

End MySection.

Section AnotherSection.

  Context {T: Type}.
  Hypothesis TEqDec: eq_dec T.

  (*          Now I must explicitly specify this -- ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ 
  Example example2: forall (t1 t2: @myType T), @f _ (@myTypeEqDec _ TEqDec) t1 t2.
  Proof. ... Qed.

End AnotherSection.
```

As you can see in example1 Coq is able to find instance-information about myType. But after I change the section, all the information about the instances disappears and I have to specify it explicitly. So, when I have many type-classes and instances, code rapidly becomes messy. Obviously, I should somehow get that information back into the context. What is the proper way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `Global` modifier to your instance declaration, like this:

```
Global Instance myTypeEqDec : eq_dec myType.
(* ... *)
```

As stated in the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual023.html),

> One can use the `Global` modifier on instances declared in a section so that their generalization is automatically redeclared after the section is closed.